# Prime ideals of ring $R = \{(a, b) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} | \, a \equiv b\, \mod 5 \}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals, ring-homomorphism

This question have two parts. I was able to do the first part.

> Consider the ring
>
> $R = \{(a, b) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} | \, a \equiv b\, \mod 5 \}$
>
> a) Show that the homomorphism $f: \mathbb{Z}[x] \rightarrow R $
>   sending $1$ to $(1, 1)$ and $x$ to $(5, 0)$ is surjective with kernel
>   $(x^2 − 5x)$.

This part was fairly easy to show. I assume it is related to the second part

> b) Find all prime ideals of $R$ containing $f(3)= 3 \cdot 1_{R}$. Then
>   find all prime ideals of $R$ containing $f(5)= 5 \cdot 1_{R}$.

For this part I am trying to use fact that pre-images of prime ideals under homeomorphism of rings are prime ideal as well. Hence pre-image of prime ideal of $R$ containing $f(3)= 3 \cdot 1_{R}$ has tobe prime ideal containing ideal $(3)\subset \mathbb{Z}[x]$. It also has to contain kernel $(x^2-5x)$.

Now part I am not sure about: since $f$ is homeomorphism we have isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-5x) \cong R$. I can show that no polynomial of degree less than $2$ is mapped to $3\cdot 1_{R}$ except for constant polynomial $h(x)=3$.

Would this somehow imply that pre-image of prime ideal containing $3\cdot 1_{R}$ is necessary $(x^2-5x, 3)$?

If this is correct, can I use same construction for $5 \cdot 1_{R}$ ?

Comment: Hint: it might be better to think about the quotient ring $S= R/P$ for a prime ideal $P$. As $P$ is a prime ideal, $S$ is an integral domain (i.e., a ring with no zero-divisors), so $P$ must "kill" one of each pair $a$, $b$ in $R$ such that $ab = 0$.

Comment: Using your hint I get $(5,0)\in P$ . Should I look on pre-image $f^{-1}((5,0))=x$ then, or should I focus only on $R$?

Comment: Not quite: either $(5, 0)$ in $P$ or $(0, 5) \in P$. I'd just focus on $R$.

Comment: OK, w.l.o.g. assume $(5,0) \in P$ and consider ideal by given $P'=((5,0),(3,3))$. Also notice that every element of $R$ is in  the form $a(5,0) + b(1,1)$. Then $R/P' = \mathbb{Z_3}$ which is field, and hence $P'$ is maximal and hence only prime ideal containing $(3,3)$, when $(5,0) \in P$ . Does this looks correct?

Comment: What is the multiplication in $R$?

Comment: @AlJebr $(a,b)\cdot(c,d)=(ac,bd)$

Comment: This probably won't help, but I just want to point out the observation that $R$ is the pullback (fibered product) of the canonical projections $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z/(5)$, i.e., $R=\mathbb Z \times_{\mathbb Z/(5)} \mathbb Z$.